# regex in URI for proxy passing

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have following config in my nginx:

```
location / {
    if ($request_uri ~* ^/checkout/(dev-dist|dist|images|js|libs|resources|angular4-hybrid|bundle.js)) {

proxy_pass http://static-qa-uscentral1.company.com/hybrid/live$request_uri;
            break;
        }
}
```

I am trying to replicate this in istio's virtual service

I have written following virtual service to match this regex:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: routes-static
  namespace: mui-relqa
spec:
  gateways:
  - my-gateway
  hosts:
  - "*"
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        regex: '^./checkout/(dev-dist|dist|images|js|libs|resources|angular4-hybrid|bundle.js).*$'
    redirect:
      authority: static-qa-uscentral1.company.com
      uri: /hybrid/live
```

Few things I would lobe to have clarity on:

1. how to use that $request_uri used in nginx config to replicate in virtual service
2. using the above virtual service it will totally redirect the calls to "static-qa-uscentral1.company.com" which I have mentioned in "authority" parameter in "virtualservice" yaml. How can I achieve what nginx does during proxy_pass which doesnot change the URL but still gets the content of redirected URL.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use Istio Envoy filter, you might want to check other rewrite options for [Envoy HTTP routing](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/v1.7.0/intro/arch_overview/http_routing#http-routing).

You can have a look at [Katacoda Migrating from NGINX to Envoy Proxy](https://www.katacoda.com/envoyproxy/scenarios/migrating-from-nginx-to-envoy). In **step 4** they show example of `proxy_pass`.

Regex will match ECMAscript style regex-based, you can even have a look into [Istio Virtual Service source code](https://github.com/istio/api/blob/master/networking/v1alpha3/virtual_service.proto).

You would need to either remove `Istio` and  setup [`NGINX Ingress Controller`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) instead, or setup the `Ingress Controller` behind `Istio` so it would redirect and/or proxy the traffic based on nginx.conf or using [`Nginx Annotations`](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md).

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
 set $agentflag 0;

 if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile)" ){
 set $agentflag 1;
 }

 if ( $agentflag = 1 ) {
 return 301 https://m.example.com;
 }
```

**Update**

This was mentioned by the OP, Envoy also supports [Lua scripting](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http_filters/lua_filter) that allows essentially injecting arbitrary code in the proxy to process requests.

Comment: I have been reading more on how to get this done using istio components only. I found "envoyFilters" in which we can write LUA code to handle something like this. Do you have any suggestions on using envoyFilters.   I really cant go back to nginx ingress controller. All our exercise is to remove nginx ingress completely and use only istio-ingressgateway. Hence istio should do TLS termination, routing, header manipulation, conditional headers everything.

Comment: @Stunn3r, You are correct I've updated my answer. Maybe this will be more helpful.